Considering Stochastic process as Random Variable Sigma-Algebra
Let's say I have a d-dimensional continuous stochastic processes $X=\left(X_t\right)_{t\geq 0}$ defined on a Probability Space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F_t},\mathbb{P}\right)$. I have read, that I can treat this process as a random variable $X:\Omega \to C\left(\mathbb{R^+,\mathbb{R}^d}\right).$ Right ?
Now I could define a Probability measure on $C\left(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ via the push forward measure. What would be the correct sigma-Algebra on $C\left(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ ?

Take the compact-open topology on $C(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathbb{R}^d)$. Now take the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(C(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathbb{R}^d))$.
The compact-open topology is also metrizable for example by the metric $d(f,g) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} d_n(f,g)$ where $d_n(f,g) = \min(1/n,\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|\ : \ x \in [0,n]\})$ for $f,g \in C(\mathbb{R}^+, \mathbb{R}^d)$. Or also by the metric $d'(f,g):= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \sup\{\min(|f(x)-g(x)|,1) \ : x \in [0,n]\}$ for $f,g \in C(\mathbb{R}^+, \mathbb{R}^d)$. This turns $C(\mathbb{R}^+, \mathbb{R}^d)$ into a complete, separable metric space, i.e. a Polish space.
